# What's the purpose of Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicValue type in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, workflow-foundation-4

I look at the documentation of VisualBasicValue in MSDN and I found nothing of clear explanation and purposes about.

I only know he resolves visual basic expressions, but I've seen VisualBasicValue used to store variablesId too:

```
var ifActivity = new If()
{
   Condition = new InArgument<bool>(new EvaluationActivity<bool>()
   {
      Expression = new InArgument<Expression>(
         new VisualBasicValue<Expression>(this.Condition.CorrelationID)
      )
   })
};
```

It was created for purposes to use with Workflow Activities? (Because he is inherit of CodeActivity).

And how he resolves the expressions? And what kind of expressions he can resolve?

Thanks.